# qTranslate issue in WordPress 4.0

Tags: wordpress, qtranslate

I have updated WordPress to latest version (4.0) this morning. After upgrading everything seems fine except qTranslate.

The editor does not show language switcher tabs and qtranslate throws following warning:

> The qTranslate Editor has been disabled because it has not been tested with this version of WordPress. This step is a safety feature to provide the functionality of a secure WordPress. To reactivate click here (may cause data loss). To remove this message, please upgrade qTranslate to the appropriate version.

On activating plugin from the click here link above, language switcher tabs are visible but they do not work as expected. When text tab is clicked it show nothing.

I had resolved same issue in WordPress 3.9.2 with the help of [this post](https://gist.github.com/warenhaus/10990386) but in new verson it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 2):

First, backup your database, then edit the main plugin file [`qtranslate/qtranslate.php`](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/qtranslate/tags/2.5.39/qtranslate.php) changing the supported version to `'4.0'`:

```
// qTranslate Editor will only activated for the given version of Wordpress.
// Can be changed to use with other versions but might cause problems and/or data loss!
define('QT_SUPPORTED_WP_VERSION', '3.8.1');
```

If there are no conflicts or bugs, the plugin should work ok.

Answer (score 2):

I've also updated qtranslate just changing the version in qtranslate.php ,
but on the [WP support blog](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/qtranslate-and-wordpress-39) I found a thread where some people also had to change a line in qtranslate_core
on line 455

```
return $before.strftime($format, $date).$after;
```

to

```
return strftime($format, $date).$after;
```

changing it didn't effect my qtrans-plugin, but keep it in mind as it maybe useful in the future.

Comment: For latest wordpress, without this change you will have this kind of errors on the log: PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class WP_Post could not be converted to string in .../wordpress/wp-content/plugins/qtranslate/qtranslate_core.php on line 455

Answer (score 1):

Including all of the above comments, following post also helps me a lot to fix the issue.

https://gist.github.com/warenhaus/10990386

Answer (score 0):

I have just installed wordpress 4.0.1, and i had the same message.
Just try this change in the following file : qtranslate/qtranslate.php, and it seems to work :

// qTranslate Editor will only activated for the given version of Wordpress.
// Can be changed to use with other versions but might cause problems and/or data loss!
define('QT_SUPPORTED_WP_VERSION', '3.8.1');

to

define('QT_SUPPORTED_WP_VERSION', '4.0.1');

Thank you, it helps a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Change access level to   **public** for those functions:

```
public display_tablenav()

public get_table_classes()
```

In **qtranslate-x\admin\qtx_configuration.php**   file.

You can see that in this version `QTX_LanguageList` extends from `WP_List_Table` class, and this ones functions are public:

```
class QTX_LanguageList extends WP_List_Table
{
    private $_clean_uri;
    private $_language_names;

    public function __construct($language_names,$clean_uri) {

        parent::__construct(array('screen' => 'language'));
        $this->_language_names = $language_names;
        $this->_clean_uri = $clean_uri;
    }

    public function get_columns() {
        return array(
            'code' => _x('Code', 'Two-letter Language Code meant.', 'qtranslate'),
            'flag' => __('Flag', 'qtranslate'),
            'name' => __('Name', 'qtranslate'),
            'action' => __('Action', 'qtranslate'),
            'edit' => __('Edit', 'qtranslate'),
            'stored' => __('Stored', 'qtranslate')
        );
    }


    protected function column_default( $item, $column_name ) { return $item[$column_name]; }
    protected function get_default_primary_column_name() { return 'name'; }
    protected function display_tablenav($which){}
    protected function get_table_classes() { return array( 'widefat', 'qtranxs-language-list' ); }
......
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It would seem that the free plugin has been killed.

But the [payed version](https://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate-xp/) is still there